# Cordova create displays no error in terminal

Tags: android, linux, cordova

I've installed Nodejs (v0.10.15) then NPM. I've already installed cordova too. So when I type `cor` and press tab it gets completed. I didn't have .bash_profile so I created it and put the following in my file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/myusername/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/home/myusername/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

I also ran the following command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

The problem is that when I type cordova create helloWorld nothing happens. What could be the matter?

The following command prints nothing on the screen:

```
cordova --version
```

Comment: did you check your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, I went to the path. It was there  ;-)